# How to handle notifications in a mobile app (websockets, kafka, redis)

Tags: node.js, apache-kafka, websocket, redis

I'm working for a company with a mobile app where users can interact with companies.

The app is made in react native

The backend was in laravel

The problem: the boss wants to implement a notification system in the app. Currently, when a user gets a private message, a push notification is triggered from firebase. But, there is no internal "notifications overview screen" in the app. And I have to develop this.

Some requirements:

- When a user gets an answer in a discussion, it should trigger a notification "someone answered your question". When someone else answers, there should not be a second notification, but the first notification should be updated to "2 persons answered your question". With some metadata like the username and the profile picture of the last commenter.
- It should be in "real time". So when the app is open and the user receives a new notification, it should not be a push notification but an in-app notification. I guess I can fix this with websocket-connections(?). I have experience with setting up websocket connections and connecting them with redis.
- When a user is offline, the notification should be stored and pushed when the user is back online (kafka?).
- I want to persist all notifications in a database. The posts are currently stored in a postgres database. Should I use the same database or should I use something like mongodb?

I have experience with redis pub/sub, but no experience with rabbitmq or kafka. I'm currently learning kafka (I've setup my local server and I'm pub/subbing messages with `kafkajs`). I have experience setting up a socket connection with nodejs and `ws`.

I'm reading up on kafka because it seems that it can "store" messages in a topic (queue). The other solution for offline users would be to create a message "queue" in redis but then I probably end up with a big redis database (the app now has around 12,000 users).

My idea so far:

- Create a kafka server with topics for `answers` and `views`. All notifications for `answers` go to this topic, for every user. I will not create a separate topic for each user.
- Create a kafka consumer in the nodejs-backend and attach it to `ws`. when a user comes online, the consumer is started. The difficulty is: when the consumer receives a message, is it deleted from the queue? Because when all messages go to the same topic, all consumers will pick up the same messages: when user A is online and B is offline, and B receives a notification, it will be picked up by the consumer initiated by user A but because user A is not the recipient (i will check this with the message content), the notification is not sent over a socket connection, but it's still deleted from the kafka topic queue? *How can I "cherry-pick" the messages in the topic I need for a specific user while keeping the others in the queue?*

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I don't think Kafka is not good choice for this. You can send events to kafka, but persist them somewhere else (not sure Redis is a good option, either)

> when the consumer receives a message, is it deleted from the queue?

From Kafka, no. Messages are kept for a week, by default. How do you plan on sending data for users gone longer than that?

> all consumers will pick up the same messages

Right. Which is why you should store data somewhere else, where you can actually filter by user

Amazon SNS / Firebase can send the actual push notifications. You don't need a websocket and a message queue to handle that.

Comment: An option can be to use push notifications with a data payload, but in my experience this is not a trudtworthy option + when users disable push notifications then they wont receive in app notifications either.

Comment: My point was that Kafka itself is a backend technology, and not integrated with any such push notification technology, and cannot be connected to from mobile clients... If you forward data to some other system, then it really doesn't matter if you used Kafka, or GCP pubsub, for example